# Count unique combination of multiple fields in a table with group by, returning only summary rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table:

| VALA | VALB | DATE | POST | VALC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | C | April 1, 2021 | 10001 | D |
| B | A | April 1, 2021 | 10001 | A |
| A | A | March 1, 2021 | 10001 | A |
| A | A | March 1, 2021 | 10001 | B |
| A | B | March 1, 2021 | 10001 | A |
| A | C | March 1, 2021 | 10001 | D |
| B | A | March 1, 2021 | 10001 | A |
| A | A | April 1, 2021 | 10002 | A |
| A | A | April 1, 2021 | 10002 | A |
| A | C | April 1, 2021 | 10002 | D |
| B | A | April 1, 2021 | 10002 | A |
| A | A | March 1, 2021 | 10002 | A |
| A | A | March 1, 2021 | 10002 | A |
| A | A | March 1, 2021 | 10002 | A |
| A | A | March 1, 2021 | 10002 | A |
| A | C | March 1, 2021 | 10002 | D |
| B | A | March 1, 2021 | 10002 | A |

I need a result set in the following format:

| POST | DATE | COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | March 1, 2021 | 5 |
| 10001 | April 1, 2021 | 2 |
| 10002 | March 1, 2021 | 3 |
| 10002 | April 1, 2021 | 3 |

What I have tried:

```
SELECT [POST]
,[DATE]
,COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY [POST]) AS [COUNT]
FROM [TABLE]
GROUP BY [POST], [DATE]
```

The problem with this:
The logic to get a COUNT of unique combinations of VALA, VALB, VALC fields are missing. It seems that the grouping is ok, but I just don't know how to continue.

Dummy data for you:

```
CREATE TABLE [TABLE] (
    [VALA] varchar(255),
    [VALB] varchar(255),
    [DATE] varchar(255),
    [POST] varchar(255),
    [VALC] varchar(255),
);

INSERT INTO [TABLE]
VALUES
('A', 'A', 'March 1, 2021', 10001, 'A'),
('A', 'A', 'March 1, 2021', 10001, 'B'),
('A', 'B', 'March 1, 2021', 10001, 'A'),
('B', 'A', 'March 1, 2021', 10001, 'A'),
('A', 'C', 'March 1, 2021', 10001, 'D'),
('B', 'A', 'April 1, 2021', 10001, 'A'),
('A', 'C', 'April 1, 2021', 10001, 'D'),
('A', 'A', 'March 1, 2021', 10002, 'A'),
('A', 'A', 'March 1, 2021', 10002, 'A'),
('B', 'A', 'March 1, 2021', 10002, 'A'),
('A', 'C', 'March 1, 2021', 10002, 'D'),
('A', 'A', 'March 1, 2021', 10002, 'A'),
('A', 'A', 'March 1, 2021', 10002, 'A'),
('A', 'A', 'April 1, 2021', 10002, 'A'),
('B', 'A', 'April 1, 2021', 10002, 'A'),
('A', 'C', 'April 1, 2021', 10002, 'D'),
('A', 'A', 'April 1, 2021', 10002, 'A');

SELECT * FROM [TABLE]
```

Thank you.

Comment: Side note: Please avoid storing your dates as _text_, because it won't sort properly.  Use an actual date column instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach uses `DENSE_RANK` to count the number of distinct combinations of the three value columns.  Then, we can aggregate by date and post and take the max value of this dense rank.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY DATE, POST
                                 ORDER BY [VALA], [VALB], [VALC]) dr
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT POST, DATE, MAX(dr) AS COUNT
FROM cte
GROUP BY POST, DATE
ORDER BY POST, DATE;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: Thank you, looks nice! May I ask you to check out my solution, if that could work as well?

Answer (score 1):

YOu might want to try the following:

```
SELECT [POST], [DATE], COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT([FUND], [GRANT], [WBS])) AS [COUNT]
  FROM [TABLE]
  GROUP BY [POST], [DATE]
```

I guess a window function such as `COUNT OVER` doesn't make sense...

Answer (score 0):

I just posted the question, but I'm trying to solve this problem for over 5 hours now, and it seems that I found a solution:

```
SELECT [POST]
,[DATE]
,COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT([VALA], [VALB], [VALC])) AS [COUNT]
FROM [TABLE2]
GROUP BY [POST]
,[DATE]
ORDER BY [POST] ASC, [DATE] DESC
```

Comment: This solution has a potential problem.  Let's say that the `VAL` columns can be either one _or_ two letters.  Then `(A, AB, C)` would appear to be the same thing as `(AA, B, C)`.  Consider using something like my answer to avoid this pitfall.

Comment: That's very true! What if insert a char in between the field values? CONCAT([VALA], '#', [VALB], '#' [VALC])). That would reduce the risk of this problem to zero if we assume that # would not appear in the value of the columns.

Comment: Yes, it would, be then using `CONCAT` in this way would make it very hard for SQL Server to use any kind of index when finding the counts.  Not to come off as a sleazy self-promoter, but I would vote for my own answer here if the site would let me `:-)`

Comment: What should I do if I need a solution using SQLite? Should I post another question, or update this one? :/ In this case, I used SQL Server to develop a query, but the application I would use the query in uses SQLite.

Comment: On recent versions of SQLite, my answer should also be working for you.